# Problems setting one-to-many relationships on PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am having a problem setting my one-to-many relationships on PHPMyAdmin

Here is tbl_books

book_id (primary key)
bookcat_id_fk (foreign key 'on update restrict, on delete restrict')
bookname
bookdesc

Here is tbl_bookcat

bookcat_id (primary key)
bookcat_name

The relationship between the two **should** be that there is ONE category to MANY books, so a one-to-many relationship.

The problem that am getting would be that I am getting the error: Duplicate entry '1' for key bookcat_id_fk

This means that I am unable to assign more books to the same category because of this, so my one-to-many relationship is not working. I have searched but I could find the answer I was wondering if you could help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your key definition `bookcat_id_fk` is UNIQUE, but without seeing the full dump don't know for sure. Anyway, I believe this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_bookcat` (
  `bookcat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bookcat_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_books` (
  `book_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bookcat_id_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bookname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `bookdesc` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE `tbl_bookcat`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`bookcat_id`);

ALTER TABLE `tbl_books`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`book_id`),
  ADD KEY `bookcat_id_fk` (`bookcat_id_fk`);

ALTER TABLE `tbl_bookcat`
  MODIFY `bookcat_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `tbl_books`
  MODIFY `book_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `tbl_books`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_books_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`bookcat_id_fk`) REFERENCES `tbl_bookcat` (`bookcat_id`);
```